# Issue with Using xdt:locator by condition "starts-with" or "contains" in Web.config Transformation

Tags: web-config-transform

I'm trying to create a web.config transform file that will change a list of appSettings value to "false" if the name contains the word "Config."

```
<add name="Config.Showlog" value ="true" />
```

The transform file has

```
<appSettings>
    <add xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" 
         value="false" 
         xdt:Locator="Condition(starts-with(@name,'Config')"/>
</appSettings>
```

Visual Studio 2010 shows an error:

> Condition Requires exactly 1 arguments.

I also tried that with Xpath as an attribute for `xdt:` locator and got the same error. It seems the problem comes from the how VS 2010 parses the expression inside `Condition()` or `Xpath()`.

How can you work around this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I came up with the following solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)"
         value="false"
         xdt:Locator="Condition(contains(@key, 'Config'))"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This will set all `value` attributes of `<appSettings><add>` elements that contain 'Config' in the `key` attribute to 'false'.

```
<add key="SomeOtherAppSettings"
     value="OriginalValue" />
<add key="An entry containing Config in the key attribute"
     value="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a bug in the `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.Dll` installed with Visual Studio 2010.

Microsoft has corrected the issue with Visual Studio 2012 RTM
([See feedback](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/618550/web-config-xpath-and-condition-locators-do-not-allow-commas-in-xpath-expression)).

For those still on Visual Studio 2010, replacing `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.Dll` in  `$(MSBuildToolsPath)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web` with updated file in `$(MSBuildToolsPath)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web` will resolve issue and allow successful build.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug with Visual Studio 2010.  Microsoft has fixed it in Visual Studio 2012

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/618550/web-config-xpath-and-condition-locators-do-not-allow-commas-in-xpath-expression